# Как добавить одну базу данных в Docker для всех микросервисов написанных на Java?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc

Псевдокод моей программы:

Клиент:

```
клиент подключается к серверу на порту 1111
```

Сервер:

```
сервер ждет клиентов на порту 1111
    здесь клиент может подключатся к какому либо микросервису, например:
    клиент подключается к микросервису регистрация на порту 2222

    и так дальше... к каждому микросервису клиент подключается по порту,
                    на котором его будет ждать микросервис
```

Микросервис 'регистрация':

```
ждет клиентов на порту 2222
```

Сейчас у меня все работает следующим образом: у меня есть три папки `Server` `Client` `Registration`, и в каждой из них лежит `File.java` и `Dockerfile` соответственно.
Что бы все запустить - я создаю в каждой папке отдельный образ, а потом по очереди все запускаю как контейнеры, и все работает на данном этапе.

Все мои микросервисы работают с одной базой данных.

Как мне можно добавить базу данных, или создать ее в `Docker` чтобы все микросервисы работали с ней и видели ее?

Когда все будет работать как надо, то я планирую создать `docker-compose.yml` в котором я буду автоматически запускать все ранее созданные мной образы всех микросервисов, но на данном этапе я хотел бы понять как правильно добавить в `Docker` базу данных что бы все микросервисы имели к ней доступ.

И еще примечание: когда я искал информацию обо всем этом, то нашел для себя много непонятных слов таких как 'Spring Boot' и 'Maven'. Как по мне я не понимаю для чего мне нужен 'Maven', так как я пишу программу которая должна работать даже через `cmd` окно, и мне не нужны какие либо 'зависимости' в этой программе и я не понимаю вообще что это такое. Можно ли обойтись без всего этого ('Spring Boot' и 'Maven')?

Comment: Если у вас микросервисы, то у каждого должна быть своя БД, а не общая. СУБД может быть одна. И тут вариантов несколько. Либо вы поднимаете контейнер с СУБД в докере (настраиваете сеть между контейнерами и т.п.), либо устанавливаете СУБД вне докера и настраиваете контейнеры для работы с ней. Если вы не видите профита от maven или spring boot, то вам это и не нужно

Comment: @ArchDemon, к примеру есть два микросервиса `Registration` и `Logging`. И у меня сейчас все в одной базе, ведь что бы проверить существует ли нужный пользователь в микросервисе `Logging` я проверяю его в той же базе, в которой я регистрирую новых пользоветелей в микросервисе `Registration`, как я тогда могу использовать разные базы данных?

Comment: `Logging` - это имеется ввиду login? Вообще сервис должен использовать внешнее API, т.е. делать http запрос к другому сервису, если ему от того нужны какие-то данные. Или второй вариант это использовать какой-то механизм оповещения, чтоб о событии создания пользователя в сервисе хранения пользователя узнавали другие заинтересованные сервисы. Через БД однозначно связывать сервисы не нужно. Использование одной БД лишает одного из важных преимуществ - возможности разрабатывать/эволюционировать сервисы отдельно, делает их сильно связанными.